# No effect of corstr argument on correlation structure in gee

Tags: r, statistics

Here is an extract from my data frame, representing results of a longitudinal study (A is  an outcome parameter measured at two time points):

```
 wide<-structure(list(ID = c(9000296L, 9001104L, 9001400L, 9001695L, 
 9001897L, 9002316L), BMI = c(29.8, 30.7, 23.5, 28.6, 25.9, 
 25.1),B.1 = c(100, 70.83, 100, 89.29, 100, 92.86), A.5 = c(100, 
 NA, 92.86, NA, 100, 89.29)), .Names = c("ID", "BMI", "A.1", 
 "A.5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 
 7L, 8L, 10L))

           wide
         ID  BMI   A.1   A.5
 2  9000296 29.8 100.0 100.0
 5  9001104 30.7  70.8    NA
 6  9001400 23.5 100.0  92.9
 7  9001695 28.6  89.3    NA
 8  9001897 25.9 100.0 100.0
10 9002316 25.1  92.9  89.3
```

As you can see, there is correlation between A1 and A5, as it should be in a longitudinal study:

```
 library (psych)


    corr.test (wide [,c(3,4)] )
    Call:corr.test(x = wide[, c(3, 4)])
 Correlation matrix 
      A.1  A.5
 A.1 1.00 0.78
 A.5 0.78 1.00
```

Then I transform my data to long format

```
    long<- reshape (wide, varying = c(3,4), direction="long")
   long
          ID  BMI time     A id
 1.1 9000296 29.8    1 100.0  1
 2.1 9001104 30.7    1  70.8  2
 3.1 9001400 23.5    1 100.0  3
 4.1 9001695 28.6    1  89.3  4
 5.1 9001897 25.9    1 100.0  5
 6.1 9002316 25.1    1  92.9  6
 1.5 9000296 29.8    5 100.0  1
 2.5 9001104 30.7    5    NA  2
 3.5 9001400 23.5    5  92.9  3
 4.5 9001695 28.6    5    NA  4
 5.5 9001897 25.9    5 100.0  5
 6.5 9002316 25.1    5  89.3  6
```

Then I try to fit gee model first using independent correlation structure:

```
     library (gee)
     model1<- gee(A~time+BMI, id=ID, corstr= "independence", data = long)
 Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
 running glm to get initial regression estimate
 (Intercept)        time         BMI 
     122.389       0.508      -1.127 

  summary (model1)

  GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
  gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

 Model:
  Link:                      Identity 
 Variance to Mean Relation: Gaussian 
 Correlation Structure:     Independent 

Call:
gee(formula = A ~ time + BMI, id = ID, data = long, corstr = "independence")

Summary of Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-17.46  -4.62   1.11   5.79  10.69 


Coefficients:
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)  122.389      34.18   3.580       31.00    3.949
time           0.508       1.60   0.317        1.12    0.453
BMI           -1.127       1.23  -0.919        1.23   -0.913

Estimated Scale Parameter:  93.6
Number of Iterations:  1

 Working Correlation
       [,1] [,2]
  [1,]    1    0
  [2,]    0    0
```

And using exchangeable correlation structure:

```
      model2<- gee(A~time+BMI, id=ID, corstr= "exchangeable", data = long)
  Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
  running glm to get initial regression estimate
  (Intercept)        time         BMI 
   122.389       0.508      -1.127 

   summary (model2)

   GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
   gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

  Model:
   Link:                      Identity 
   Variance to Mean Relation: Gaussian 
   Correlation Structure:     Exchangeable 

  Call:
  gee(formula = A ~ time + BMI, id = ID, data = long, corstr = "exchangeable")

  Summary of Residuals:
    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
  -17.46  -4.62   1.11   5.79  10.69 

  Coefficients:
             Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
  (Intercept)  122.389      34.18   3.580       31.00    3.949
  time           0.508       1.60   0.317        1.12    0.453
  BMI           -1.127       1.23  -0.919        1.23   -0.913

  Estimated Scale Parameter:  93.6
  Number of Iterations:  1

Working Correlation
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    0
 [2,]    0    0
```

As you can see, the outputs are identical in spite of using different correlation structures in gee models. In both instances the correlations are zero in the correlation matrices.

In my actual data I have many more observations and time points, but there are also within-subject correlations which are significant. However all gee models (also using different dependent variables) also has zero correlations in their correlation matrices and changing corstr argument does not lead to changes in the model output. 
All this seems very strange. 
Could you please suggest what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution!
ID variable should be sorted!

```
  long<-long [order(long.p$ID),]



        model1<- gee(A~time+BMI, id=ID, corstr= "independence", data = long)
       Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
      running glm to get initial regression estimate
      (Intercept)        time         BMI 
        122.389       0.508      -1.127 

        model2<- gee(A~time+BMI, id=ID, corstr= "exchangeable", data = long)
        Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
      running glm to get initial regression estimate
       (Intercept)        time         BMI 
          122.389       0.508      -1.127 
        Warning message:
        In gee(A ~ time + BMI, id = ID, corstr = "exchangeable", data = long) :
         Working correlation estimate not positive definite




> model1

GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

Model:
Link:                      Identity 
Variance to Mean Relation: Gaussian 
Correlation Structure:     Independent 

Call:
gee(formula = A ~ time + BMI, id = ID, data = long, corstr = "independence")

  Number of observations :  10 

Maximum cluster size   :  2 


  Coefficients:
 (Intercept)        time         BMI 
122.389       0.508      -1.127 

  Estimated Scale Parameter:  93.6
  Number of Iterations:  1

  Working Correlation[1:4,1:4]
       [,1] [,2]
       [1,]    1    0
       [2,]    0    1


          Returned Error Value:
        [1] 0
          model2

        GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
       gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

      Model:
       Link:                      Identity 
          Variance to Mean Relation: Gaussian 
       Correlation Structure:     Exchangeable 

      Call:
  gee(formula = A ~ time + BMI, id = ID, data = long, corstr = "exchangeable")

   Number of observations :  10 

  Maximum cluster size   :  2 


   Coefficients:
 (Intercept)        time         BMI 
 180.00       -1.70       -3.16 

 Estimated Scale Parameter:  154
 Number of Iterations:  5

 Working Correlation[1:4,1:4]
      [,1] [,2]
  [1,]  1.0  2.8
  [2,]  2.8  1.0


  Returned Error Value:
  [1] 1000
```